# Олимпиадная задача Черепаха

Tags: python, олимпиада

Решал  [задачу](https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=1966&chapterid=894#1)

> Домик черепахи расположен в начале прямой узкой грядки, на которой
> должны прорасти одуванчики – ее любимое лакомство. И вот черепахе
> приснился вещий сон. Из него она узнала, что наконец-то после полуночи
> начнут расти одуванчики. Ей даже приснилось, в какой момент времени, и
> в какой точке грядки вырастет каждый одуванчик. Ровно в полночь
> черепаха выползла из домика, чтобы съесть все одуванчики и до
> следующей полуночи вернуться домой.
>
> Черепаха может ползти со скоростью, не превосходящей величины vmax.
> Одуванчик она съедает, остановившись на время d. Если одуванчик начать
> есть, но не доесть до конца, то он засыхает, поэтому его надо съедать
> за один прием. Одуванчики прорастают тем позже, чем дальше они
> расположены от начала грядки. В одной точке не могут прорастать
> несколько одуванчиков, а также несколько одуванчиков не могут
> прорастать в один момент времени.
>
> Требуется определить, в какой момент времени черепаха сможет вернуться
> домой, съев все одуванчики и затратив на путешествие наименьшее время.

Алгоритм решения: бинарный поиск в интервале от 0 до максимального времени прорастания.
Ищем середину. Если получилось, что время, в которое мы подползли к одуванчику больше либо равно времени прорастания этого одуванчика, то увеличиваем счетчик количества съеденных одуванчиков и к времени прибавляем d. После того, как прошлись по всем одуванчикам, кроме последнего, прибавляем к общему времени, время, за которое черепаха проползет расстояние от предпоследнего до последнего одуванчика. Теперь, если время равно времени прорастания одуванчика - то на выход, если больше - то идем в левый интервал, если меньше то в правый.

Получился вот такой код, но он не проходит все тесты. Прошу помощи в доработке кода, так как у меня ментальный затык.

```
import math

v, d = map(int, input().split())
n = int(input())
R = []
T = []
for i in range(n):
    x, t =input().split()
    x = int(x)
    h, m = map(int, t.split(":"))
    if i == 0:
        R.append(x)
    else:
        R.append(x-R[i-1])
    T.append(float(h*60+m))
    if i == n-1:
        z = x
L = 0
PR = max(T)
k = 0
while PR-L > 0:
    M = (L+PR)/2
    t = M
    for i in range(len(R)-1):
        t += R[i]/v
        if t >= T[i]:
            t += d
            k += 1
    t += R[-1]/v
    if t == T[-1]:
        break
    elif t > T[-1]:
        PR = M
    else:
        L = M
t += z/v+(n-k)*d
t = math.ceil(t)
h = t//60
m = t%60
print(str(h).zfill(2)+":"+str(m).zfill(2))
```

Comment: оффтоп, но вот, от ментального затыка: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging мне иногда помогает

Comment: *Если получилось, что время, в которое мы подползли к одуванчику больше либо равно времени прорастания этого одуванчика, то увеличиваем счетчик количества съеденных одуванчиков и к времени прибавляем d* Явная ошибка. некоторые выгоднее сжевать на обратном пути. Надо ориентироваться на последний (который последний как в грядке, так и по времени прорастания).

Comment: @Akina Дело в том, что последний в грядке и последний по прорастанию это в общем случае разные одуванчики.

Comment: *последний в грядке и последний по прорастанию это в общем случае разные одуванчики* Так... вот это кто пишет: *Одуванчики прорастают тем позже, чем дальше они расположены от начала грядки.* А?

Comment: @Akina это условие задачи. Возможно вы и правы, но я не понимаю как это учесть в коде.

Comment: Для минимизации времени надо приползти к последнему цветку как можно раньше, но не раньше его прорастания. Из этого определяется, сколько цветков можно сжевать по дороге "туда".

Comment: @Akina так я вроде бы так и делаю.

Comment: Непонятно, при чём тут вообще бинарный поиск. Это же самое обычное прямое сканирование...

Comment: @Akina не уложится по времени. Нужно перебирать задержку с шагом 0.1 минута.

Comment: А перебирать-то зачем? Просто тупо ползём, накапливая текущее время. Если между двумя цветками километр, зачем шагать по сантиметру?

Comment: `R.append(x-R[i-1])` - посмотрите, что делает эта ваша строка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, я постарался минимально изменять ваш код, чтобы он залетел:

```
import math

v, d = map(int, input().split())
n = int(input())
R = []
T = []
z = 0
for i in range(n):
    x, t =input().split()
    x = int(x)
    h, m = map(int, t.split(":"))
    R.append(x-z)
    T.append(float(h*60+m))
    z = x

L = 0
PR = max(T)
for i in range(100):
    M = (L+PR)/2
    t = M
    for i in range(len(R)-1):
        t += R[i]/v
        if t >= T[i]:
            t += d
    t += R[-1]/v
    if t == T[-1]:
        break
    elif t > T[-1]:
        PR = M
    else:
        L = M

t = 2*z/v+n*d+PR
t = math.ceil(t)
h = t//60
m = t%60
print(str(h).zfill(2)+":"+str(m).zfill(2))
```

Изменения затронули вашу ошибку во вводе, когда вы при расчете разницы между двумя соседними иксами считали разницу между иксом и предыдущей разницей.

Также я изменил вид цикла и расчет t после него. Почему-то без обоих этих изменений у меня не получалось загнать ваш код.